# Regex for item dimensions

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
(\d+\.?\d*)(?=.*)(\d+\.?\d*)|(\d+\.?\d*).+diam
```

However, it's not working fully. It's picking up '24K Gold' It should only pick up 2 valid numbers with an x in the middle somewhere.

[Current regex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrU6o.png)

EDIT:

Examples:

**Input:**

```
40cm x 100cm

2.3 x 8.6

height: 100cm x width: 200.2cm

25K Gold

60 diam

50 diam
```

**Output:**

```
40, 100

2.3,8.6

100,200.2

60

50
```

Comment: Please provide some some text example that you are working with. And give an example of the result you want to get with that regex.

Comment: @h-sifat Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this single numbered text like:

25K Gold

60 diam

50 diam

```
/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/
```

And for two numbered text like:

40cm x 100cm

2.3 x 8.6

height: 100cm x width: 200.2cm

```
/(\d+(\.\d+)?).*?x.*?(\d+(\.\d+)?)/
```

your first and second number will be in the first and second capturing group consequently.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value with an x in between, and not match `25K Gold`, `60 diam` and `50 diam` you could use

```
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[^\dxX\n]*[xX][^\dxX\n]*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `[^\dxX\n]*[xX][^\dxX\n]*` Optionally match any char except `x` or `X` and then match `x`
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qV7n4P/1)